# Recuperar users de uma determinada localidade com API Facebook

Tags: facebook, api

Gostaria de saber como eu consigo montar uma requisição HTTP para a API do Facebook, que me retorne todos os usuários de uma determinada localidade.

Exemplo:https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305 retorna o JSON para um post.
No meu caso gostaria de um JSON com os users de uma localidade específica.

Answer (score 1):

Através da API do Facebook você pode obter a lista de amigos de um usuário que estão próximos a este usuário.

A maneira como você construiu sua pergunta contudo dá a entender que você deseja obter uma lista de usuários genérica associados a uma localização (não uma lista de amigos de um usuário), e não é possível obter essa informação por questões de privacidade.

Comment: Como não? Responde completamente. Não existe como fazer o que ele quer.

Comment: É só citar uma referência relevante e a resposta já vira canônica.

Comment: @lolol, por que está muito abstrata e sem referencias que comprovem o que você afirma, e não explica, o por que de isso não ser possível, nem cita possíveis opções como [listar amigos próximos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/friendlist). Com um pouco mais de cuidado e carinho ela fica boa. Só sinalizei como forma de alertar, pois da maneira que está não ajuda muito, mas parece um comentário a pergunta.

Comment: A pergunta dele é uma requisição que retorne todos os usuários (não amigos!!!) ao redor de uma localidade, e isso não é possível fazer. Óbvio que não existe uma referência para isso. Vou elaborar contudo, tem razão.

Comment: @lolol, agora, está um pouco melhor, já dá pra ser considerado uma resposta. Hehe.